# ¿Cómo poder ocultar contenido ajeno dentro de un iframe?

Tags: javascript, c#, mvc

Necesito ocultar unos logotipos dentro de un `iFrame`, el problema aquí es que el contenido es de un dominio ajeno, he leido que no se puede por cuestiones de seguridad, así que quisiera saber si tienen alguna otra alternativa para poder hacer lo que necesito, adjunto imagen para poder ser mas descriptivo.

[image: necesito esconder esos 2 logotipos que situan en la parte de arriba]

He intentado hacerlo por JavaScript pero me topo con la sorpresa de que me bloquea el *script* por las mismas razones de seguridad, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de MVC estás utilizando?

Comment: uso la version 5

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener permiso desde el servidor donde se encuentre el `iFrame` o este debe estar en tu mismo dominio. Esto debido a las políticas `Same-Origin` y/o `Cross Domain`

Answer (score 0):

No sé puede hacer eso, el `iFrame` muestra la página completa y listo, no hay mucho que puedas hacer, si intentas modificalo con *scripts* no podrás justo por esos temas de seguridad.

La unica forma posible es si ambos pertenecen al mismo dominio.

Lo mas cerccano que puedes hacer es mostrar solo una parte especifica de la web que está dentro del iframe con el div, de esa manera solo se mostrará lo que necesites sin el header que es donde está el logo.
Algo como ésto.

```html
<div style="width:1000px;height:1000px; position:relative; overflow:hidden">
        <iframe src="http://www2.repuve.gob.mx:8080/ciudadania/" style="top:-95px; position:absolute"width="1000" height="1000" scrolling="yes" frameborder="1" >
<p>texto alternativo para navegadores que no aceptan iframes.</p>
</iframe></div>
```

Si vas a http://www2.repuve.gob.mx:8080/ciudadania/ puedes ver la página original y si das ejecutar acá podes ver como le quito la parte donde se encuentran los logos, quizas te sirva. También puedes quitarle parte de abajo o de los costados.

Saludos

Comment: hola alexis, me podrias agregar a skype por favor?
marvel_nemesis_11@live.com.mx

Comment: solicitud enviada

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es obtener el HTML del embebido en el servidor en lugar de hacerlo en el cliente porque tendrás una restricción de seguridad al ser dominios cruzados. Una vez que en C# has obtenido el HTML, el cliente debe solicitalo y convertirlo a un documento.

En lugar de ponerlo en un iframe, pon la URL del sitio externo en un atributo `data-src`:

```
<div class="embed" data-src="url del embebido"><div>
```

Luego, solicitas al servidor que haga un scrapping de dicha URL y te devuelva el HTML:

```
let embed = document.querySelector('.embed');
let url = encodeURIComponent(embed.getAttribute('data-src'));

fetch (`/get_iframe?url=${url}`)
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(parseHTML.bind(embed, this);

function parseHTML(node, html) {
  let doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, 'text/html');
  while (doc.body.firstChild) {
   node.appendChild(doc.body.firstChild);
  }
}
```

En este punto, en lugar de tener el `iframe` tienes un `div` con el contenido de la URL externa y puedes editar su contenido con puro CSS.